# How to make a navigation bar permanently on top?

Tags: css, html, web, web-development-server

Can i make a navigation bar always on top?

i am not talking about the : position: fixed; thing...

the problem with my navbar is that when you zoom it out it is not on top anymore...

how can i make it like this site's navigation bar where is is always on top when you zoom it out?

or

is there any chance that i can make it like facebook's navbar (the one on top which says home)
that has a FIXED position but still the same when zoomed in or out.

the code for my whole css is here and the html for the navbar is there also

if you want to check the site the link is:

http://hyperraze.comxa.com/

Thanks

```css
 ul.navbar{
 float: left;
 display: inline;
}

#hyper{
 position: relative;
 top: 70px;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity: 0.9;
}

a.navbar{
 display: inline;
 padding: 9px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 background-color: #009900;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-right: 53px solid red;
 width: 70px;
}

a.navbar:hover{
 color: #009900;
 background-color: blue;
}

div.navbar{
 border: 0px;
 background-color: red;
 width: 40000px;
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 623px;

}


#link1,#link2,#link3,#link4,#link5,#link6,#link7{
 position: relative;
 bottom: 9px;
}

#cons{
 position: relative;
 top: 150px;
 width: 250px;
 z-index: -1;
}

h1{
 color: yellow;
 font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

h2{
 color: #009900;
 text-align: center;
 font-family:'Orbitron', sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 top: 120px;
 font-size: 60px;
}

#data{
 color: #b2950b;
 text-align: right;
 font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
 position: relative;
 top: 300px;
 font-size: 17px;
}

#marq{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: black;
 position: relative;
 top: 70px;
 font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="dmenu" class="navbar">
<center>
<ul><a class="navbar" id="link1" href="index.html">HOME</a></ul>
<ul><a class="navbar" id="link2" href="index.html">GAMES</a></ul>
<ul><a class="navbar" id="link3" href="index.html">TUTORIAL</a></ul>
<ul><a class="navbar" id="link4" href="index.html">GAMERS</a></ul>
<ul><a class="navbar" id="link5" href="index.html">CONTACT</a></ul>
<ul><a class="navbar" id="link6" href="index.html">ABOUT</a></ul>
<ul><a class="navbar" id="link7" href="index.html">DONATE</a></ul>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Note, the `center` tag is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: Neither is `marquee`. I mean, dude! :p

Answer (score 2):

You have to use: `top: 0;` instead of `bottom: 623px;` for `div.navbar`. Using `bottom` property is why your `div.navbar` element goes down when someone zooms out the page.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this class:

```
div.navbar{
border: 0px;
background-color: red;
width: 40000px;
height: 50px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
position: fixed;
top:0; /*added this*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By default, things **always** flow from top to bottom regardless of zoom.

While you can try to source for a bandaid that works, I think you're going down a seriously problematic, wrong path. From your code, it is clear that you have a lot of misunderstandings about HTML and and how elements are styled.

What you should really do is basically revamp the whole page:

1. Fix the multiple syntax problems in your site/understanding - `<center>`, `<marquee>`, `<font>`, `<ul>` without `<li>`, mixed up closing tags, scripts outside of `</html>`, `bgcolor` attribute...
2. Then, layout your site from TOP to BOTTOM using proper HTML.

From what I guess, you want something like this:

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <a id="link1">...</a>
    <a id="link2">...</a>
</nav>

<img id="logo" src="..." alt="Awesome Logo" ...>

<h1>...</h1>
<h2>...</h2>
```

3. Add in your CSS without touching the HTML.

You will realise you don't actually need to do anything special to get it to stay at the top - it simply always does.